# Excel SUM function is not working (shows 0), but using Addition (+) works

Tags: excel

I'm stumped in Excel (version 16.0, Office 365). I have some cells that are formatted as Number, all with values > 0, but when I use the standard SUM() on them, it always shows a result of 0.0 instead of the correct sum. When I use + instead, the sum shows correctly.

For example:

- SUM(A1:A2) shows 0.0
- A1 + A2 shows 43.2

I don't see any errors or little arrows on any of the cells.

Comment: I could not produce this behavior only by entering data as text (with small backtick). In all other cases, both functions work the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Excel is telling you *(in an obscure fashion)* that the values in **A1** and **A2** are `Text`.

The `SUM()` function ignores text values and returns zero.  A direct addition formula converts each value from text to number before adding them up.

Comment: Thanks, yes, using NUMBERVALUE() on every cell fixed it. I wish there was an easier way to set a cell type than having to use a function on every one. Some of these cell definitions can get very long and complex, and anything to reduce the length of complexity would be helpful.

Comment: It's confusing because in almost all the documentation I've found, they use "format" and "type" interchangeably. Most of the pages tell you tell you to set the type of a cell by changing its format. Like this:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel/excel_setting_cell_type.htm

Comment: Just had this problem for a working excel sheet... moved rows, all cells having type "Currency" but SUM() is not able to sum.... changing to "Number" did not help - removed values and entering again + using a+b and later sum solved it... (for me it looks like a bug in Excel Web, using Excel Web)

Comment: Another source of the problem is the "Fixed" worksheet Function. It returns TEXT. Useful for presentation/display, but cells later referencing cells containing "Fixed" may not Sum correctly. Wrapping in NumberValue will indeed avoid that symptom.

Answer (score 8):

Using NUMBERVALUE() on each cell fixed it. Even though each cell was formatted as a Number, since the data was originally extracted from text, the cell contents apparently were NOT being treated as a Number. Yet another flaw in Excel.

Comment: Are you using any formulas to extract the numbers?

Comment: "Yet another flaw in Excel" - not exactly. Formatting, and the underlying value, are not the same. If you want a number, you actually have to convert it to a number... (e.g., nothing happens if you apply the Number format to a cell containing the text "foo", and similarly, nothing happens if you apply number formatting to a cell containing the *text-that-looks-like-a-number* "1").

Comment: @BigBen - your comment is helpful. I know how to enter 'text that looks like a number' - by putting a single apostrophe (') at the start of the cell. But I've just downloaded a spreadsheet from my verizon account, and all the 'numbers' are flagged with a small green triangle upper-left, and a warning 'the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe' - but - I see no apostrophe (even in edit-mode), and I changed the format to 'number' but it made no difference. BUT - the 'warning' has the option to 'Convert to number' - and that fixes it! But I can't do it manually.

Comment: @Steerpike - not all text-that-looks-like-a-number is preceded by an apostrophe. For example, format a new cell to text, then type any number in it.

Comment: @BigBen - agreed; format new cell as text, type number in it - the 'number' typed is actually 'text'. But then, change cell format back to 'number', and that 'text' content remains (any FUTURE entry in that cell will be 'number' but the information you entered remains as text).  Only way I found to convert EXISTING text content is to use 'Data/text-to-columns' - that will convert in-place.  You'd think, in the 'format' dialog, there'd be a check box for 'convert existing content' or similar.

Comment: @Steerpike - there are definitely other ways to convert in place. For example, put 1 in a new cell, copy the new cell, then select the text-that-looks-like-a-number, paste special > multiply.

Answer (score 7):

I get a similar issue while importing from a csv.
Selecting the cell range and formatting as number did not help
Selected the cell range then under:
Data -> Data Tools -> Text to Columns -> next -> next -> finish
did the job and numbers are now turned into numbers that excel consider as numbers !
This avoids use of NUMBERVALUE()

Comment: The above method worked like a cham!; Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a much faster way you just need to replace all the commas by points.
Do control-F, go to "Replace" tab, in "Find what" put "," and in "Replace with" field put "."

Comment: Can you explain your answer? I'm not sure what commas are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if the sum contains formulas if you have any issue with circular references they won't work, go to Formulas-->Error checking-->Circular References and fix them

Answer (score 0):

If there's a tab in your .csv then Excel will interpret it as text rather than as white space.  A number next to a tab will then be seen as text and not as a number.  Convert your tabs to spaces with a text editor before letting Excel at it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem by replacing all Number's "." with "."

How the heck can this be real? Feel really misunderstood by Excel....

Comment: Are you saying that you just replaced all dots with dots? Or is there a typo in your answer?

Comment: Yes exactly, no typo there. It was very weird but worked for me 

Comment: Worked for me too. A SUM() of a range was showing 0.0 as a result. Changed dots to dots as suggested, and the correct sum was shown.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers showing up as numbers when they are actually texts.
Using the ERROR sign next to the cell to convert the "text" into a numbers looks like the only uncomplicated solution that works. Hectic when working with huge amounts of data. a bug in excel<<<

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, in excel2007, since a column contains mixed value number with strings, I needed doing some steps:

1. I Removed "," on colonn data source (column A) with "Replace" Excel option.
2. I Created a column without all text in my case strings are 6 last characters. I removed with this formula:
   `=left(E2; NBCAR(E2)-6)`.
3. I created a column C to transform possible string to number with function formula.
4. If "#VALUE!" is showed on "Sum" cell, check last cells have a string.

```
A2  Remove ","          -->  B2 Remove text with formula --> C2 Show value with "cnum"
1,894,529.000000BTC|         =left(A2; NBCAR(A2)-6)          =cnum(b2)
```

Good sum's ;)